# Is using AWS SDK to launch an instance and aws cli to manage it a good approach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I've just started with AWS and I have some questions.

First, I followed the official documentation on how to launch an instance using AWS SDK for JAVA like this:

```
    AmazonEC2 Client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsCreds);
    CreateSecurityGroupRequest csgr = new CreateSecurityGroupRequest();
    csgr.withGroupName("Azzouz_group").withDescription("My security group");
    IpPermission ipPermission = new IpPermission();
    ipPermission.withIpRanges("0.0.0.0/0").withIpProtocol("tcp");
    AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest = new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();

    authorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.withGroupName("Azzouz_group").withIpPermissions(ipPermission);


    RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

    runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-4b814f22")
            .withInstanceType("m1.small")
            .withMinCount(1)
            .withMaxCount(1)
            .withKeyName("azzouz_key")
            .withSecurityGroups("Azzouz_group");

    RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
    RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

    String instanceId = runInstancesResult.getReservation().getInstances().get(0).getInstanceId();
```

I didn't use the `CreateKeyPairRequest` part because I want to upload my public key to amazon so when I try to `ssh` into into I don't have to add `-i path/to/key.pem` and I have only to mention the key name in my java code (`"azzouz_key"`) , in the next lines, `$USER` contains `azzouz_key`:

```
keypair=$USER  # just a name
publickeyfile=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
regions=$(aws ec2 describe-regions \
  --output text \
  --query 'Regions[*].RegionName')

for region in $regions; do
  echo $region
  aws ec2 import-key-pair \
    --region "$region" \
    --key-name "$keypair" \
    --public-key-material "file://$publickeyfile"
done
```

what I want now is connect to the instance and automate some stuff. So I 'm heading to make a call to a shell from inside the java code, the script  gets an instance id as a parameter, then gets the ip adress ( using `aws ec2 describe-instances` ), ssh into it and do some stuff.

I wanted to authorize ssh connection to the instance from any ip just as a start(0.0.0.0/0) and I'm not sure if this is what I'm supposed to do.

So, my question is: Is this the best approach?! Should I just use the aws cli to create and manage the instance?! Does just mentioning just the key pair name fits with the mechanism of uploading the public ssh key to amazon?!

Please, I'm just starting, I'm an intern and I dont yet have an access to an amazon account so I can test my work. I'm just working all of this in my mind. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

my advice is to setup an account on AWS and start using the AWS free tier options.

All in all, it is there and it is for free (just pay attention on what you launch or use in the service).

Apart of that, your question about how to authorize connections over SSH from everywhere, this is done over security groups (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

About what is the best option, this really depends on you.

If you need to launch 2 instances in your life on AWS, then the console is good enough. If you want to orchestrate your hybrid setup, then probably your way is the best.

CLI is an excellent solution for daily operations too.

In simple words, there is not best way or a good or bad approach. It all depends on your needs.

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much Maurizio. About the free tier account, it needs a credit card, and in my country we don't have such cards. That's the problem so I'm waiting for my boss to grant me an access next week.

Comment: Right, unfortunately no credit card no party on AWS.

Is there a way to obtain a virtual credit card in your country?

Answer (score 1):

Automation is a huge topics.If you want to extend AWS automation using script,  Before touching the API/SDK, first, you must design your own AWS resources tags naming.

Tags naming is an implicit ways to reference to AWS resource without explicitly specify the resource-id(e.g. VPC id, EC2-id ,interface-id,etc). In addition, for resource such as EC2 that doesn't allow immediate use of tag during creation, you need to study usage of "client-token".

AWS CLI allow you to do lots of automation, however, to manipulate response result, you need shell script skill to manipulate them. I suggest you pick the AWS SDK language that you are familiar with.

Cloud configuration management tools(there is limited support from tools like Ansible, saltstack,puppet) can be the next step, if you plan to extend the whole source deployment, server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider starting off with Infrastructure as Code. Cloud Formation with Code Pipeline will ensure automated and consistent environment launches and makes you highly valuable in the marketplace.

Both can be launched and managed via the awscli. As your capabilities and the complexity of your IaC increase it may be worth looking into Terraform due to the modularity available compared to CloudFormation.